# Ruby require directive causes an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flickr

Trying to create a simple flickr application using Ruby on Rails 3.2.3, I faced a problem. First I installed a gem called `flickraw`

```
sudo gem install flickraw
```

Then I tried to use it

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'flickraw'

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def index2
  end

  def index3
  end
end
```

And I got an error:

**LoadError in HomeController#index**

```
cannot load such file -- flickraw
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not require gems from the controller. You should just add flickraw to your Gemfile

```
gem "flickraw"
```

Comment: When I try to do this I get the following error msg: `Unknown command flickraw`. Any idea what to do in order to solve it?